# Record camera preview with overlay using Android MediaRecorder

Tags: android, android-camera

We need some help on "How to record video along with the overlay image?"

Here is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ......
    ......
    >
    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Preview"
        />      
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TemplateFrame" 
        android:background="@drawable/template04"
        >       
        <DigitalClock 
            android:id="@+id/digitalClock" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="DigitalClock" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            > 
        </DigitalClock>                                   
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        ......
        ......
        >                   
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/capture_button"
            android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
            />      
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

WHERE,

```
"@drawable/template04" is a transparent PNG file.
```

Please let us know your views.

Regards